# The Guyabano uprising: How is this going to be dealt with?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, new-users

In a span of about two hours, four questions (one of which is unintelligible) regarding smoking some fruit ("Guyabano" or the Soursop fruit) have cropped up. They've been posted through 4 *different* accounts.

I'm talking about these posts:

- [Is guyabano vape juice is safe to use?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82974/is-guyabano-vape-juice-is-safe-to-use)
- [Is it safe to vape guyabano leaves?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82981/is-it-safe-to-vape-guyabano-leaves)
- [What is the reaction of inhaling mixed propylene glycol and vegetable glycol in our health?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82984/what-is-the-reaction-of-inhaling-mixed-propylene-glycol-and-vegetable-glycol-in)
- [Does chemical compounds of guyabano leaves mixed with smoke when burned?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82985/does-chemical-compounds-of-guyabano-leaves-mixed-with-smoke-when-burned)

I've flagged one of them ('bout 2 hours ago?) for moderator attention, but it appears my flag hasn't been looked into (No Mods around now...well, my bad luck I guess?).

**Besides, what's going to be done about this?**

**Are the four posts going to be merged/purged? What about the accounts?**

The users in question claim that they are *different* people (see comments section in the second post).

Also, the third and fourth posts are aren't *exactly* the same as the first two...but they're all made in the same vein...

---

Also,

**What should I, as a responsible(-ish) user, do when some fiasco like this happens again. Leave a ton of comments below the posts? Flag each post? Do both?**

---

**EDIT:**

The first post (the one written in Filipino) has been deleted, so I've retracted my  flag (which I raised at the second question)

> [image]

Comment: downvote + closevote + cvs from other people = taken care of

Comment: what's "cvs" ? (I'm trying to learn the jargon)

Comment: @Mith I see! Well, I guess that's the logical/standard line of action. But what about the user(s) and the whole multiple account thing? Well, none of the accounts have gained any rep (and they're unlikely to be used in the future), so ignoring it is the way to go, I guess? Thanks! :D

Comment: @S.Chevalier "CVs" = "Close-votes". You need 3ooo+ rep to see/cast close votes and reopen votes ;)

Comment: Thanks! I know about privileges, I just couldn't decipher the pluralised abbreviation. Abbreviations are hard on my french brain. ^^

Comment: Or flag + downvote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. In this case, I personally don't see an urgent need to do anything. On your part, you just need to downvote and/or flag and/or vote to close, as with all low-quality questions. On our part, the duplicates will be subject to merging and probably also deletion, but that isn't a super urgent process.

Mods are busy people - most of them have actual jobs, except for myself; but even that will change soon, as I will be much busier from next week onwards. I don't mean this in a *"don't disturb us"* sense - please disturb us if you think something is up - I just mean that it's normal if flags don't get dealt with within a few hours.

Generally, there are very few things that actually require *immediate* moderator action, anyway.

Comment: Ah, looking back, I guess I was over-reacting to this. Probably because I don't see stuff like this happen often (kudos to le Mods for keeping the front page clean!). I think I (kinda) understand what you mean by the "*very few things that actually require immediate moderator action*", I'll save up my *para*noia (pun intended) for when that happens. Thanks, and apologies for making a mountain out of mole-hill O:)

Comment: @paracetamol Yeah, unless it's graphically obscene or something, it can wait whatever few hours it takes until a mod drops by their flag queue.

Comment: --- @hBy2Py ---- Brian Oooh! "Graphically obscene", eh? 3:)  Waiting to see that happen -------->

Comment: @paracetamol Oh, it already has, believe me. It's just been *very* rapidly handled by (our very excellent) mods.

Comment: Actually, @hBy2Py, even those can be dealt with reasonably quickly by the community, using rude or abusive flags. I am not going to suggest what sort of incident might require immediate mod action, as I don't want to give anybody any ideas :)